# API issue: Products not retrieved in Flutter restaurant app

Tags: android, flutter

In my Flutter restaurant app, the products are not showing on the restaurant's page. The terminal log is:

```
product-api->http://dbsfsood.coriftjoasket.com/app/v1/api/get_products
I/flutter (3470): product-body->{limit: 10, offset: 0, partner_id: 45, filter_by: p.id, latitude: 25.661413, longitude: 94.0988732, user_id: 9, city_id: 1, category_id: 2}
I/flutter (3470): product-data->{error: true, message: Products Not Found!, data: []}
```

The product data is populated in the database but is not showing.

I have access to the server, and this is the API code for the `get_products` parameter:

```
get_products
    id:101              // optional
    category_id:29      // optional
    user_id:15          // optional
    search:keyword      // optional   // search by product name and highlights
    tags:multiword tag1, tag2, another tag      // optional {search by restro and product tags}
    highlights:multiword tag1, tag2, another tag      // optional
    attribute_value_ids : 34,23,12 // { Use only for filtration } optional
    limit:25            // { default - 25 } optional
    offset:0            // { default - 0 } optional
    sort:p.id / p.date_added / pv.price
                        { default - p.id } optional
    order:DESC/ASC      // { default - DESC } optional
    top_rated_foods: 1 // { default - 0 } optional
    discount: 5             // optional
    min_price:10000          // optional
    max_price:50000          // optional
    partner_id:1255           //{optional}
    product_ids: 19,20             // optional
    product_variant_ids: 44,45,40             // optional
    vegetarian:1|2|3             //{optional -> 1 - veg | 2 - non-veg | 3 - Both}
    filter_by:p.id|sd.user_id       // { p.id = product list | sd.user_id = partner list }            
                            { default - sd.user_id } optional      
    latitude:123                 // { optional }
    longitude:123                // { optional }
    city_id:1                    // { optional }
    partner_slug : mcdonalds
```

How do I analyze this issue and resolve the problem? I am 100% sure that this is an API issue and not a flutter code issue.

Comment: You can check your API using postman, whether the API is giving a proper response or not. Then you can integrate API with your app.